# Does it matter in which order I list the following on an input element?

Tags: javascript, order-of-execution

In the code below, I am curious if it matters in which order I put the name, id, class, type, and value. I would assume it doesn't really matter, but then I begin to wonder about using it with JavaScript and load times. If I am triggering the input based in the ID with JavaScript, would it be better to place the id first? Would that increase load times? Or is the order of these things just plain insignificant?

```
<input name="last_name" id="last_name" class="placeholder" type="text"  value="" />
```

Comment: Good question, but don't worry about it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order makes no difference.

Hooking in to an ID on an element will only work once the element is loaded into the DOM. Attribute order has no effect on this.

Answer (score 1):

The order of attributes has absolutely nothing to do with load times or the functioning of the attributes unless perhaps you have a duplicate attribute (which is not what you're asking about here).

If you are running code that will operate on the id value in this piece of HTML, that code can't run until the relevant pieces of the page are fully loaded (e.g. in the DOM to be found and safely operated on) anyway so there's no way the order of the attributes will affect when the whole object is ready or when your code can run to operate on the object.